# Solving the recurrence relation $x_{n+2}-5x_{n+1}+6x_{n}=5^{n}+n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> SOLVE: 
>   $x_{n+2}-5x_{n+1}+6x_{n}=5^{n}+n$

---

How to deal with it?

I use method:
$r^2-5r+6r=0$
$x_{n}=A*2^{n}+B*3^{n}+..$

I can deal with similar problems:
$x_{n+2}-5x_{n+1}+6x_{n}=5^{n}$ or $x_{n+2}-5x_{n+1}+6x_{n}=n$ but I have no idea for $x_{n+2}-5x_{n+1}+6x_{n}=5^{n}+n$

Comment: Set $$x_n=y_n+a+bn+cn^2$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the left side of your equation is linear in the $x_n$'s. Therefore, if you have two solutions, one for $\ldots=5^n $ and one for $\ldots=n $. Then the solution to the full problem is just the sum of the two solutions.